# When implementing an interface that has a method with 'in' parameter by TypeBuilder.CreateType, TypeLoadException is thrown

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, reflection.emit, typebuilder

Using `TypeBuilder`, I'm building a class that implements an interface that contains a method. After implementing that method with `ILGenerator`, then I call `TypeBuilder.CreateType()` and everything goes well in the normal case.
But if the method contains any parameter with the `in` modifier, also known as *readonly reference* for value types, `TypeBuilder.CreateType()` throws *`TypeLoadException("Method 'SomeMethod' ... does not have an implementation.")`*.

Unlike the usual case of `TypeLoadException` that implemented method with the same signature as the one declared in the interface(s) doesn't exist, this problem is raised only when the method contains `in` parameter(s) even signatures are the same. When I remove or change the `in` modifier to `ref` or `out`, `TypeBuilder.CreateType()` successfully recognizes the generated method as an implementation of one declared in the interface, and the type is built normally.

Here's a fully compilable example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Threading;
 
namespace EmitMethodWithInParamTest
{
    public struct StructParam
    {
        public String Data;
    }
 
    public interface ISomeInterface
    {
        Int32 SomeMethod(in StructParam param);
    }
 
    static class EmitExtension
    {
        public static void ReplicateCustomAttributes(this ParameterBuilder paramBuilder, ParameterInfo paramInfo)
        {
            foreach (var attrData in paramInfo.GetCustomAttributesData())
            {
                var ctorArgs = attrData.ConstructorArguments.Select(arg => arg.Value).ToArray();
 
                // Handling variable arguments
                var ctorParamInfos = attrData.Constructor.GetParameters();
                if (ctorParamInfos.Length > 0 &&
                    ctorParamInfos.Last().IsDefined(typeof(ParamArrayAttribute)) &&
                    ctorArgs.Last() is IReadOnlyCollection<CustomAttributeTypedArgument> variableArgs)
                {
                    ctorArgs[ctorArgs.Length - 1] = variableArgs.Select(arg => arg.Value).ToArray();
                }
 
                var namedPropArgs = attrData.NamedArguments.Where(arg => !arg.IsField);
                var namedPropInfos = namedPropArgs.Select(arg => (PropertyInfo)arg.MemberInfo).ToArray();
                var namedPropValues = namedPropArgs.Select(arg => arg.TypedValue.Value).ToArray();
 
                var namedFieldArgs = attrData.NamedArguments.Where(arg => arg.IsField);
                var namedFieldInfos = namedFieldArgs.Select(arg => (FieldInfo)arg.MemberInfo).ToArray();
                var namedFieldValues = namedFieldArgs.Select(arg => arg.TypedValue.Value).ToArray();
 
                var attrBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(attrData.Constructor,
                    ctorArgs, namedPropInfos, namedPropValues, namedFieldInfos, namedFieldValues);
                paramBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attrBuilder);
            }
        }
    }
 
    class Program
    {
        static Program()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us");
        }
 
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("DynamicAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
            var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
            var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("SomeClass",
                TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.AutoClass | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit | TypeAttributes.AutoLayout,
                null /*base class*/,
                new[] { typeof(ISomeInterface) });
 
            var methodInfoToImpl = typeof(ISomeInterface).GetMethod(nameof(ISomeInterface.SomeMethod));
            var paramInfos = methodInfoToImpl.GetParameters();
 
            var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(methodInfoToImpl.Name,
                MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.Final,
                CallingConventions.HasThis,
                methodInfoToImpl.ReturnType,
                paramInfos.Select(pi => pi.ParameterType).ToArray());
 
            foreach (var paramInfo in paramInfos)
            {
                // paramInfo.Position is zero-based but DefineParameter requires 1-based index.
                var paramBuilder = methodBuilder.DefineParameter(paramInfo.Position + 1, paramInfo.Attributes, paramInfo.Name);
                if (paramInfo.Attributes.HasFlag(ParameterAttributes.HasDefault))
                {
                    paramBuilder.SetConstant(paramInfo.DefaultValue);
                }
                paramBuilder.ReplicateCustomAttributes(paramInfo);
            }
 
            // Dummy implementation for example. Always throws NotImplementedException.
            var ilGen = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(NotImplementedException).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
            ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Throw);
 
            var builtType = typeBuilder.CreateType();               // <- TypeLoadException("Method 'SomeMethod' in type 'SomeClass' from assembly 'DynamicAssembly, ...' does not have an implementation.") is thrown.
            var generatedObj = (ISomeInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(builtType);
 
            var someParam = new StructParam() { Data = "SomeData" };
            var result = generatedObj.SomeMethod(in someParam);     // <- NotImplementedException expected by dummy implementation if executed.
 
            Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
        }
    }
}
```

This code is also uploaded to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/sNn2Rky9).

While digging down this problem, I found that the `in` parameter has two custom attributes, `InteropServices.InAttribute` and `CompilerServices.IsReadOnlyAttribute`. But when I generate a method without implementing the interface *(this succeeds normally because no signature matching required)*, `in` parameter of generated method has only one custom attribute, `InAttribute`. So I replicated all custom attributes of parameters from the interface, but still TypeLoadException is being raised.

I've tested this on `.NET Framework 4.6.1` and `.NET Core 2.2` with `C# 7.2 and 7.3`. And all environments gave me the same exception. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows.

Is there anything that I have missed or are there any workarounds?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Could you post a minimal compilable example here? Off-site links often decay.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I posted whole example code to [pasebin](https://pastebin.com/sNn2Rky9). This code was compilable on Visual Studio 2017 as a single file. If you need solution and project files too, please let me know. Thanks for your time for this question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry, I misread your comment that mentioning about off-site link.
I thought the code I pasted to pasebin is the minimal compilable code but it's too long to be embedded here(slightly over 100 lines). Would it be no problem to be pasted here?
Addition: I read your additional comment after writing this comment. I'll post whole example now. Thanks for your advice. :)

Comment: I think what you're missing is `typeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride(methodBuilder, methodInfoToImpl);` to link the interface method implementation - however, there's a follow-on bug from there (I don't have time to look right now)

Comment: @MarcGravell I didn't know about `DefineMethodOverride` method, but in the [document from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride?view=netframework-4.8#remarks), it's saying,
"*Do not use this method to emit method overrides or interface implementations. To override a method of a base class or to implement a method of an interface, simply emit a method with the same name and signature as the method to be overridden or implemented, ...*".

Comment: And I tested with calling `DefineMethodOverride` just before calling `CreateType`, and `CreateType` threw TypeLoadException too, but with different message, "*Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match, ...*". So, we seem to have no luck yet.
But I really appreciate for using your time for this question. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After writing the question above, I've been investigated built binary of sample code in IL and source code of [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) for a few days, and now I found the problem and solution.

In short, required and optional custom modifiers of return type and each parameter type take a part of method signature like each types do, and it had to be replicated manually. I thought that it will be done by passing `ParameterAttributes.In` to `MethodBuilder.DefineParameter` and replicating the custom attribute `InAttribute`, but it was wrong.

And, among `in`, `ref` and `out` modifiers, only `in` emits a required custom modifier to specified parameter. In contrast, `ref` and `out` are represented only with their type itself. This is the reason why only `in` didn't work as expected.

To replicate custom modifiers, call to `TypeBuilder.DefineMethod` need be modified like this:

```
var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(methodInfoToImpl.Name,
    MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual | MethodAttributes.Final,
    CallingConventions.HasThis,
    methodInfoToImpl.ReturnType,
    methodInfoToImpl.ReturnParameter.GetRequiredCustomModifiers(),      // *
    methodInfoToImpl.ReturnParameter.GetOptionalCustomModifiers(),      // *
    paramInfos.Select(pi => pi.ParameterType).ToArray(),
    paramInfos.Select(pi => pi.GetRequiredCustomModifiers()).ToArray(), // *
    paramInfos.Select(pi => pi.GetOptionalCustomModifiers()).ToArray()  // *
    );
```

Marked lines with `// *` are newly added to replicate custom modifiers of return/parameter types.

Or, we can do this by calling `MethodBuilder.SetSignature` method after calling `DefineMethod` without any type and custom modifiers arguments. If we decided to call `SetSignature` separately, we need to call it before any `DefineParameter`, `SetCustomAttribute`, `Equals(Object)`, `SetImplementationFlags`, getter of property `Signature` and many other methods that call the internal method `MethodBuilder.GetMethodSignature()` that cache bytes representing method signature.

Comment: Peculiarly, I had spotted the extra custom attribute on the in parameter, and added them with a ParameterBuilder to add the In attribute. And then added the platform-dependent IsReadOnly attribute. And still failed to match the override. This works. I still don't know which attributes I was missing And has the advantage of pre-anticipating all kinds of pain.The Select's are particularly elegant!